# Spring data jpa with java FX

Tags: spring, spring-boot, javafx-8, openjfx, spring-boot-jpa

I'm using Spring JPA with OpenJFX. It's this project [JavaFX-weaver](https://github.com/rgielen/javafx-weaver/tree/master/samples/springboot-sample), simply adding spring-boot-start-data-jpa inside pom.

However my starting time of Spring JPA is 15-20s and the UI will not show until spring is initalized. When users will start the application it takes a lot of time, every time!

As a workaround i tried to create a simply java fx application without Spring (using this demo [here](https://github.com/openjfx/samples/tree/master/HelloFX/Maven/hellofx)) and then starting there in the main method the main method from spring over a button (see example bellow). That will start spring, but dependencies and properties are not laoded.

Do you know a good way to practice that case ? Every help is welcome.

Thank you

## AppBootstrap (Java + OpenJFX)

```
public class AppBootstrap extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Button btn = new Button();

        // start spring jpa main method
        btn.setOnAction(event -> App.main(new String[]{""})); 

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

## App (Spring JPA + javafx-weaver)

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(SpringbootJavaFxApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Startup of an JPA powered Application increases load time for ApplicationContext. While you can make things faster by not checking or creating a database scheme, e.g. by setting `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=none`, this is not the best option.

It is by design that the primary stage is shown *after* the ApplicationContext is loaded, since it should be able to be dependency injected.

The best practice I recommend is using a splash screen while loading the ApplicationContext. It's a bit tricky, since you have separate Threads, but roughly it looks like this:

**Create a splash window**

```java
public class Splash {

    private static final int SPLASH_WIDTH = 200;
    private static final int SPLASH_HEIGHT = 200;

    private final Parent parent;
    private final Stage stage; 

    public Splash() {
        this.stage = new Stage();
        stage.setWidth(SPLASH_WIDTH);
        stage.setHeight(SPLASH_HEIGHT);
        Label progressText = new Label("Application loading ...");
        VBox splashLayout = new VBox();
        splashLayout.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        splashLayout.getChildren().addAll(progressText);
        progressText.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        splashLayout.setStyle(
                "-fx-padding: 5; " +
                        "-fx-background-color: white; " +
                        "-fx-border-width:5; " +
                        "-fx-border-color: white;"
        );
        splashLayout.setEffect(new DropShadow());
        this.parent = splashLayout;
    }

    public void show() {
        Scene splashScene = new Scene(parent);
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        final Rectangle2D bounds = Screen.getPrimary().getBounds();
        stage.setScene(splashScene);
        stage.setX(bounds.getMinX() + bounds.getWidth() / 2 - SPLASH_WIDTH / 2.0);
        stage.setY(bounds.getMinY() + bounds.getHeight() / 2 - SPLASH_HEIGHT / 2.0);
        stage.show();
    }

    public void hide() {
        stage.toFront();
        FadeTransition fadeSplash = new FadeTransition(Duration.seconds(0.3), parent);
        fadeSplash.setFromValue(1.0);
        fadeSplash.setToValue(0.0);
        fadeSplash.setOnFinished(actionEvent -> stage.hide());
        fadeSplash.play();
    }
}
```

**Initialize Application**

```java
public class SpringbootJavaFxApplication extends Application {

    private ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

    class ApplicationContextLoader extends Task<Void> {

        private final Stage primaryStage;

        ApplicationContextLoader(Stage primaryStage) {
            this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void call() {
            ApplicationContextInitializer<GenericApplicationContext> initializer =
                    context -> {
                        context.registerBean(Application.class, () -> SpringbootJavaFxApplication.this);
                        context.registerBean(Stage.class, () -> primaryStage);
                        context.registerBean(Parameters.class,
                                SpringbootJavaFxApplication.this::getParameters); // for demonstration, not really needed
                    };
            SpringbootJavaFxApplication.this.context = new SpringApplicationBuilder()
                    .sources(JavaFxSpringbootDemo.class)
                    .initializers(initializer)
                    .run(getParameters().getRaw().toArray(new String[0]));

            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        var splash = new Splash();
        splash.show();
        final ApplicationContextLoader applicationContextLoader = new ApplicationContextLoader(primaryStage);
        applicationContextLoader.stateProperty().addListener((observableValue, oldState, newState) -> {
            if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                context.publishEvent(new StageReadyEvent(primaryStage));
                splash.hide();
            }
        });
        new Thread(applicationContextLoader).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        this.context.close();
        Platform.exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. thats a nice solution exactly what searching for.. great